# Update only 1 row in database with items that have the same name

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sql-update

I have a datagridview and a button, when button is clicked selected row should be updated. Everything works fine until I have to update item with the same name (TICKER), then all items with that name are updated.

Is there a possibility to update row based on ID even though ID isn't visible?

Here is my code :

```
 Dim myCONN As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=w:\Portfolio.mdb")
                       Dim query As String = "UPDATE PFT SET [Sell Price]=?, [G/L (USD)]=?, [G/L (%)]=?, BS=? WHERE TICKER=?"

            myCONN.Open()

            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, myCONN)

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[Sell Price]", Label7.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[G/L (USD)]", Label18.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[G/L (%)]", Label28.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("BS", "S")
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TICKER", Label26.Text)


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
            myCONN.Close()
```

Comment: Why don't you use some easy-to-understand parameter names? and try to correct your sql query

Comment: if you have more than one row with the same TICKER, thats pretty much whats supposed to happen.  if you are trying to make somethign like a trading history you will need something to distinguish one row from another, like a Date or AutoNumber PK

Comment: @AliRashidi OleDB doesnt actually use named params, they are positional.  his `.AddWithValue` should just be "@p1, @p2" or something abstract like that so that he doesnt think he can in fact add them by name in any order.  Something like he has does help map the order to the poorly named Labels

Comment: @Plutonix Yes pretty much. Since data is in Access database I have ID column but don't know how to use that?

Comment: for a trading history and if this is like a Sell record, it should be an INSERT not UPDATE.  I should think in most cases that once something is SOLD it remains sold forever and doesnt need an UPDATE

Comment: @Plutonix I've tried that with G/L% and get the same error : No Value given for one or more parameters

Comment: @Plutonix I am using only one row for 1 trade buy/sell when security is bought "B" is added to BS column, when sold "B" is changed to "S". And sell price, date and etc. are added

Comment: `one row for 1 trade` would mean a B row for each BUY and a distinct S row for each SELL. Your way seem to rule out making sense out of the data if you Sell some today then next month buy some back. OTOH if you are recording G/L then you only need S records, but potentially many per TICKER. No idea what `G/L% and get the same error...` means or refers to.

Comment: For each new buy new row is created with "B" indicator, after a while that owned security is sold and "B" is changed to "S" and that row will never be updated again (it's history). I've didecide not to use loops to display G/L in sold part of the portfolio but to updated those record when security is sold, otherwise (when security is bought but not sold) those gain/loss columns are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an ID you just need to add it to the SQL and then pass the value of the
ID for the row you wish to update:

```
Dim query As String = "UPDATE PFT SET [Sell Price]=?, [G/L (USD)]=?, 
        [G/L (%)]=?, BS=? WHERE (TICKER=? AND ID = ?) "

myCONN.Open()

Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, myCONN)
    ' OleDb just maps values based on ? positions in SQL
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Label7.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Label18.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", Label28.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", "S")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", Label26.Text)

    ' new param to pass the ID from wherever you have it stored
    ' variables work just as good as UI controls, BTW
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", Label??????.Text)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Note that the "S" param is not needed.  The SQL could just as easily be `"[G/L (%)]=?, BS='S'..."`

Any db Column which is not text/string/char should be converted.  For instance, if `[Sell Price]` is a Decimal:

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Convert.ToDecimal(Label7.Text))
```

I also simplified the parameter designation to generic "@pN", because OleDB does not use named parameters: they are filled in by the order they appear in the SQL.  Treating them as named params can result in errors if you dont place them in that same order.